# Remove commit on now deleted files

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have clean my repository using `git filter-branch` to remove some folders using the following command:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch folder' \ 
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

After this, I still have some commits that are only relevant for now-deleted files. Is there a way to clean this, i.e., remove commits on files that are not in the history anymore?

Comment: I _think_ that you'd have to affect history in order to do this, is this a problem?

Comment: @OliverRadini Not at all, I already modified the history while removing the folders.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

If there really are some, you can just run an otherwise-no-op second filter-branch with `--prune-empty` to discard them.

#### Long, with experiment

> After this, I still have some commits that are only relevant for now-deleted files.

That should be rare, because you included:

> ```
> --prune-empty
> ```

which directs `filter-branch` to omit any simple (non-merge) commit that matches its parent.

It's possible you have some merges that merge two branches that are otherwise identical at their input points, but these commits cannot be removed because they merge the branches that are otherwise identical.

Suppose, for instance, we have the following branch structure before the filtering:

```
          B--C
         /    \
...--o--A      M--o--...
         \    /
          D--E
```

Commit `M` is a merge and must be preserved (so it is), but suppose `A`-vs-`B` collapses away because after filtering, `B` matches `A`, and `C`-vs-`B` (or vs-`A`) also collapses away for the same reason, giving:

```
...--o--A'-----M'-o--...
         \    /
          D'-E'
```

(the tick marks or prime symbols after the letters indicate that these are copies of the original commits—it's possible `A'` *is* `A`, if nothing earlier changed, but this covers the more general case).  Here `M` really is still required to maintain the logical structure, even though it would have been possible to do a fast-forward, had the commits been made without the removed files originally.

The more interesting case is when `D` and `E` themselves collapse away, because now `M` still exists as an input to the filter-branch process, and still has two parents, but *both parents map to commit `A'` itself*.  I'm not sure, without looking, what happens here: can filter-branch make a merge commit with `A'` listed twice as the two parents for `M'`?  If it attempts this, does `git commit-tree` write commit `M'` as an ordinary, non-merge commit?  Testing says no:

```
$ mkdir mtest
$ cd mtest
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo test commit-tree > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 1db1f76] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ echo log msg | git commit-tree -p HEAD -p HEAD HEAD^{tree}
error: duplicate parent 1db1f76a4e7217d5198c0f178464b7a087e94078 ignored
44f91061b7bd08c39a4dc9e8ebb1f4f7c588ea9e
```

So it appears that a naive `filter-branch` will attempt to make `M'` and will make it as a single-parent commit:

```
...--o--A'-M'-o--...
```

where `M'` and `A'` have no differences.  The filter-branch code has a check for this though:

```
    for parent in $parents; do
            for reparent in $(map "$parent"); do
                    case "$parentstr " in
                    *" -p $reparent "*)
                            ;;
                    *)
                            parentstr="$parentstr -p $reparent"
                            ;;
                    esac
            done
    done
```

(If you provide your own parent filter, this happens after the checking, and you will need your own re-checking.)

So, if you are getting this kind of `...--A'-M'-...` result, a second filter-branch with just `--prune-empty` will toss them out.

Comment: I already tried another `git filter-branch --prune-empty` but the commits are still there. I checked with `git show` that these commits only contain changes on files that have been deleted by the first `git filter-branch`.

Comment: Be careful with `git show` and merge commits: Git will by default show a *combined diff*, which omits files on purpose to make the diff more useful. Add `-m` to make Git diff against each parent. (If they're not merge commits, I'm not sure what is going on here.)

Comment: I tried `git show -m COMMIT_ID`, and I have the same output.

Comment: Hm, wait, are you looking at *unfiltered* commits? Remember that `git filter-branch` simply *copies* all the commits as needed; the originals are still there. If you use updated references, you see the updated commits, but if you use raw hash IDs, you can still see the originals.

Comment: I am looking at commit returned by `git log`, aren't these updated?

Comment: They should be. For me to do anything more at this point I'd need to see the repository and the commits... (or a simple reproducer, if you can construct one)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180854/discussion-between-holt-and-torek).

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in step 6 on this page: https://github.com/epics-modules/motor/wiki/Creating-a-standalone-driver-module

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --parent-filter 'sed "s/-p //g" | xargs -r git show-branch --independent | sed "s/\</-p /g"'
```